# Вывод денег из аккаунтов Google Play и AdMob

Tags: android, google-play, admob, монетизация

**Дано:**

Накоплена минимально возможная для вывода сумма денег в аккаунтах магазина приложений и `AdMob`.

Есть гражданство РФ, паспорт РФ, бумажная открытка от `AdMob`-a, доставленная почтой России из Калифорнии (с пинкодом), подтверждающая, что я реальный человек, вот это всё.

В Интернетах множество разной степени устарелости инфы на счёт вывода доходов. Начиная с чеков, доставляемых почтой России и кончая договорами с фирмами-резидентами США, кои получают, берут процент и отправляют разработчику остаток.

**Возможное решение:**

Вот сейчас посмотрел в настройках аккаунтов - вроде как в обоих есть опция указать реквизиты долларового банковского счёта, коий позволяет получать деньги по `SWIFT`. Звучит просто - идёшь в банк (я спрашивал в СберБанке про открытие счёта - говорят только паспорт нужен), открываешь счёт => отсылаешь гуглу реквизиты => получаешь *честно* нажитые...

**Возможные проблемы:**

Изначально то ли напутал, то ли опции такой не было - в `Play Market` я указан как юридическое лицо и поменять (как я понял по отсутствию соответствующей кнопки в настройках аккаунта и как на хабре читал) уже ничего нельзя (т.е. указать себя физическим лицом). В `AdMob`-e значусь физическим лицом.

**Вопрос:**

Стоит ли мне считать достаточным открытие долларового счёта и отсыл его реквизитов гуглу для получения денег с обоих аккаунтов? Какие могут быть подводные камни? Что там с налогами (подоходный там, НДС, etc)? Когда-то на хабре видел статейку с переводом на русский договора гуглового маркета с разработчиком, коий, якобы, какой-то банк у кого-то требовал. Неужто тоже надо? Ну и разные мелочи типа дат, по коим "з/п" приходить будет, интересуют)

Comment: Юрий, не подскажете, как вы в итоге поступили? 

Долларовый счет открыли в Сбере, в Tinkoff или другом банке? 
Конкретно из Google Play получилось таким образом деньги вывести? 
Были ли еще какие-то тонкости или проблемы или все достаточно прозрачно: вбиваешь свой ИНН, реквизиты счета и ждешь перевода?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Марат Гилязов, счёт в сбере делал. Деньги пришли и из GP и с AdMob. Всё в итоге было очень просто. ИНН вообще не понадобился. Только реквизиты. Вот вам ссылка с некоторыми подробностями: http://hashcode.ru/questions/387921#387959

Comment: А возможен ли вариант вывода средств резиденту РФ на карту Латвийского банка?
Просто, думаю, это получается необходимо регистрировать латвийский акк в Google Play, и подвязать мою карту этой же страны, интересно как Google относится к таким моментам, или можно  регистрировать и РФ акк, но банковскую карту как-то указать Латвийскую, не интересовались таким моментом?

Comment: @Dragic, я не специалист, но, думаю, ежели вы можете сделать всё как резидент РФ (и акк и счёт), то проще так. А потом уже, получив денежки, переводить их на любой другой счёт.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Я решил это так:

1. Получаем ИНН в родной налоговой. Это довольно просто, кстати. Можно подать заяву через сайт налоговой - назначат время и получаешь бумажку с ИНН
2. Получаем карту банка Tinkoff (не реклама!) - можно оформить в онлайне, сами приедут и привезут в офис/домой
3. Карта этого банка (в отличие от сберовской) автоматически привязана к забугорному счету (что-то типа Chase Manhattan) - со всеми нужными SWIFT'ами и проч.
4. Идем в гуглевский аккаунт и забиваем туда реквизиты + ИНН
5. Опля, и через некоторое время смска из банка известит о поступлении тугриков на счет карты. Тугрики поступают раз в месяц в начале месяца.
6. Далее, самое важное - надо раз в год подавать декларацию о доходах в своей налоговой и отнять 13% от кровно заработанных - иначе жди беды!

P.S. По-поводу юр/физ лица на маркете - напишите в поддержку гугла и они исправят это.

Comment: ИНН есть, но я не очень понял из вашего ответа для чего он нужен. Для налоговой? 

А если мне из идеологических соображений хочется именно российский банк, то никакой разницы ведь не будет, да?

Comment: Насколько я помню - ИНН требует Google - там несколько раз менялись правила съема денег, в какой то момент требовался ИНН - сейчас не могу точно сказать нужен он или нет.

Comment: Видать опять поменяли. Нигде упоминаний ИНН не вижу, только инфу по счёту требуют.

Comment: Связался с саппортом гугла.

Сообщили, что все всегда значатся как "юридическое лицо" (в merchant center), а вот в налоговой информации можно уже свободно, в любой момент, выбрать кто ты: транснациональная мега-корпорация или индивидуальный предприниматель.

Про ИНН сказали, что он им обычно не нужен, особенно если ты из РФ. А так они могут потребовать США-аналог ИНН в не понятых мною случаях.

Ещё они добавили багованную (по умолчанию Алтай указан) фичу выпадающего списка с регионами РФ в адресе, в коей есть и Крым и Севастополь. Давать комментарии по этому поводу отказались)))

Comment: >иначе жди беды
Насчет этого пункта подробнее пожалуйста. Кто может эту беду принести и как?

Comment: @Deadkenny согласно налоговому кодексу РФ [подлежат декларации](http://www.nalog.ru/rn61/taxation/taxes/ndfl/):

>физические лица, резиденты РФ по доходам, полученным от источников, находящихся за пределами РФ;

К коим относится в т.ч. доходы полученные от Google Play

Google в Соглашении о распространении продуктов отдельно предупреждает разработчиков, что уплата налогов является заботой самих разработчиков:

> Разработчик несет ответственность за уплату налогов в соответствующие налоговые органы

Так что надо декларировать доходы и уплачивать 13% налог с полученных сумм.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Ну это понятно, но как налоговая узнает о ваших поступлениях, если ей не говорить, например.

Comment: @Deadkenny не надо считать всех идиотами. В налоговой не все дураки. Достаточно задать 1 вопрос по приходам в ваш банковский счет и все.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Да я и не считаю, просто не знаю, как эта схема вся работает. Читал на хабре, как парень решил все по-честному сделать, так его гоняли полгода и тюрьмой грозили.

Comment: @Barmaley, подскажите как правильно заполнить реквизиты банка Тинькофф в Payments Merchant Center? В Тинькофф просят обязательно заполнять основание платежа, но в google простонет такого поля. Есть "Для последующего зачисления", но там всего 35 символов позволительно, портянку от Тинькофф туда не вместить :-(
Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Впишите туда просто свое имя, можно написать "FFC <User Name>" - FFC==For Further Credit Of (для дальнейшего зачисления)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а что насчёт валютного контроля? Насколько я знаю - единственные способы избежать его на данный момент: это western union (и иже с ними) , или карта европейского банка(например литовская). А валютный контроль, это очень геморойно, молодым предпринимателям он приходит нежданно, и сулит часто полной потерей месячного дохода.

Comment: Не в курсе по-поводу валютного контроля. У меня с этим проблем пока нет - тьфу-тьфу