# Регистрация аккаунта разработчика Google Play и вывод денег в России

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Мне нужно создать аккаунт разработчика в *Google Play* для того, чтобы выкладывать свои приложения и получать денежные средства с рекламы в этих приложениях. Какой банковский счёт для этого нужен? Где нужно регистрироваться? Какие есть нюансы при выводе денег в России? Я хотел бы поподробнее узнать про регистрацию аккаунта разработчика в *Google Play*, про то, какая кредитная карта для этого нужна, и где её получить, и про вывод денег в России.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

1. Нужна карта с возможностью платить в Интернете для первоначального взноса в 25 долларов в Google Play (заплатить надо всего один раз, в отличие от яблочного акка разработчика, где платить надо раз в год). Лично я пользовался виртуальной QIWI-картой. Для её получения нужна SIM-карта (для регистрации аккаунта в QIWI). Далее, на сайте или в приложении создаёте карту с любыми данными о владельце и платите.
2. Нужен долларовый счёт с возможностью получать доллары из-за границы. Мне помог в этом Сбербанк (счёт открывают за $5, которые оказываются неснимаемой суммой на счету. Счёт называется "Универсальный"). Дали бумажную книжку по паспорту, реквизиты. Ввёл это в аккаунте - деньги пришли. Далее, если хочется удобств - можно оформить сбербанковскую же карту (за 780 рублей в виде страховки единовременной. Далее можно и не платить её. Нужен паспорт). С ней можно в онлайн-банке доллары в рубли перевести на карту и с карты уже в банкомате наличные снять. Либо по старинке отстоять очередь в отделении и снять наличные по паспорту и книжке.
3. Для рекламы нужен отдельный аккаунт. В моём случае - AdMob. Там всё так же, за исключением первоначального взноса. Но есть один нюанс: после достижения некой пороговой суммы доходов за рекламу будет плашка в аккаунте повешена с предложением вбить адрес для высылки бумажного (sic!) письма с пин-кодом, который должен (после его получения и вбития в аккаунте) убедить AdMob в том, что вы реальный человек. Идёт оно из Калифорнии, готовьтесь к его длительному ожиданию.
4. Сама регистрация не сложная. Просто вбиваем запрашиваемые данные.

**Итог:** Нужны SIM-карта, банковская карта, паспорт РФ, 30 долларов и чуть-чуть прямых рук.

**P.S.** Вот тут ещё чуть-чуть информации: [Вывод денег из аккаунтов Google Play и AdMob](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383937/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-google-play-%D0%B8-admob).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ещё хотелось бы ещё узнать, можно ли проделать эти операции, если мне 16 лет?

Comment: Нет. Карты, счета и симки только с 18. Делайте всё на родителей или знакомых, коим доверяете. Только вот врятли потом можно на себя переписать это всё. Придётся как-то выкручиваться)

Comment: А можно ли через два года в аккаунте разработчика будет поменять счёт, на который будут капать деньги?

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, вообще да. Чего-то я немного не подумал) Можно будет в 18-ть всё на себя оформить в аккаунтах. Вбить свою карту, адрес, счета.

Comment: Юрий, вы писали "Для рекламы нужен отдельный аккаунт. В моём случае - AdMob.". Это значит, на одном гугл аке (почта) - акк разработчика, а для AdMob следует заводить еще один? Т.е. на одной и той же почте (гугл аке) не стоит делать?

Comment: @texx, надо бы это не в виде ответа на вопрос делать, а в виде вопроса, в коем дать ссылку на сей вопрос, ответ и мой акк.

По существу: нет, можно оба акка (гугл-плей и адМоб) создать на одну учётку гугло-почты.

P.S. На всяких там хабрах пишут, что акки иногда банят. В этом случае, **может быть**, если акки будут на разных почтах, то не забанят сразу оба акка.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, ошибся) Спасибо за ответ - в сети не могу найти вообще никакой информации по этому вопросу. А суть вопроса - возможные баны или другие негативные последствия сбора всего "в одну корзину" (один гугл акк). Вы делаете на разных?

Comment: @texx, я фаталист и ленив. Засим всё у меня на одной почте. Если есть опасения, что забанят, то лучше на разные почты, конечно, регать акки. Но это **не гаранирует**, что не забанят оба акка. Кто их знает - как там они в гугле всё делают?

Comment: Можно вопрос, в гугл консоли для подтверждения личности требуется фотография паспорта, не может ли возникнуть проблем с тем, что мне 16 лет?

Comment: @Lms, этого я не знаю. По фото они определять ваш возраст точно не будут, а вот по дате рождения... Может быть. Но это опять таки не значит, что вас сразу забанят. Надо изучать текст договора с разработчиком на предмет ограничений по возрасту. Может там и есть запрет такой.

Comment: Ну по крайней мере в РФ полная административная ответственность с 16, так что наверное должно нормально всё быть

Comment: @Lms, Лучше убедитесь, что это разрешено Гуглом. Ему плевать за законы стран

Answer (score 16):

Добавлю ещё три вещи:

1. долларовый счёт не обязателен. Деньги автоматически конвертнутся в валюту счёта
2. приходят они очень быстро, через 2-3 дня
3. Гугл плей требует так называемый BIK банка. Обычно его при международных платежах никто не спрашивает. Короче, это внутрероссийский БИК. На листочке с реквизитами банки обычно его не указывают, но его легко нагуглить в инете