# Вопрос по поводу аккаунта разработчика в Play Market

Tags: android, google-play

Такой вопрос, у меня уже есть стандартный аккаунт в Play Market, можно ли из него сделать аккаунт разработчика? или надо новый аккаунт регистрировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под "стандартным" вы имеете в виду тот, что позволяет скачивать приложения, то нет. Аккаунт разработчика это отдельная штука. Его даже можно на то же "мыло" зарегать, что и стандартный акк.

Вот вам инфы ещё по вопросу: [Регистрация аккаунта разработчика Google Play и вывод денег в России](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387921/android-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-google-play-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 2):

Аккаунт разработчика - это аккаунт, отличный от обычного аккаунта Google, который имеют огромное количество людей по всей планете. Чтобы получить возможность публиковать свои творения в GooglePlay, необходимо не только зарегистрироваться как разработчик, но и заплатить деньги( не большие, но 25$ ).