# Добавление карты в Google аккаунт

Tags: android, google-play

Регистрирую аккаунт в [Google Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/)

при нажатии на "Continue to payment" меня просит ввести номер карты, дату окончания, CVC-код.

**Вопросы:**

1. Для чего гугл будет использовать эту карту ? (кроме того, что оплатить 25 вечнозеленых за акк)
2. Можно ли как-то обойтись без ввода карты(например оплатить через терминал) ?
3. Можно ли потом удалить/изменить номер карты ?

Возможно можно создать виртуальную карту какую-то и ее ввести?

П.С. Не хочу, чтобы у гугла были мои данные банковской карты и тд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Гуглу надо лишь единоразово оплатить $25. Это [можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/387959/17609) и виртуально картой сделать. Далее эти данные вообще не нужны.
2. Нет, но карта может быть виртуальной, ненастоящей, см. ссылку из п.1.
3. См. п.1 и п.2.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А Киви карту, как я понял можно просто привязать к сим-ке и никак тебя не идентифицируют, верно ?

Comment: @researcher, да, всё верно. Когда я карту делал через киви, то там автоматом подставлялись значения типа "Иванов Иван Иваныч".

Answer (score 1):

Аккаунт разработчика **платный**. Именно для этого он и просит карту.
Внимательнее посмотрите на страницу, на которую вы привели ссылку, там это все написано.

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю это. вопрос не в этом. сейчас подправлю вопрос.