# Каков путь начинающего разработчика android?

Tags: java, android, google-play

И так видел некоторых разработчиков в гугл плей, у которых есть только калькулятор с 10-50 загрузками и решил тоже так поступить, но возникла проблема - нужно 25$ для регистрации и уже желание пропало... Можно ли как-то бесплатно опубликовать бесплатное приложение? Или же как начать свой путь (начиная с создания простых калькуляторов, по которым кликают только знакомые и до уже большого проекта в несколько тысяч скачиваний).
ps видел статью на хабре ( https://habrahabr.ru/post/144359/ )
И 2 вопрос - как вставить простую рекламу в приложение? Чтобы друзья кликали и как-нибудь за год соберу пару $

Comment: А тут как регистрироваться и выводить деньги: [Регистрация аккаунта разработчика Google Play и вывод денег в России](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/387959/17609)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> но возникла проблема - нужно 25$ для регистрации и уже желание пропало...

Видимо не такое уже и большое у вас желание. Для сравнения: Apple берет до 99$ в год, в зависимости от типа приложения.

> Можно ли как-то бесплатно опубликовать бесплатное приложение?

В Google Play никак, разве что в другие бесплатные маркеты. Но в той же статье, что вы указали, в комментариях человек привёл пример, когда с одного и того же приложения в Google Play 400k загрузок, а с бесплатных маркетов суммарно меньше 100.

> И 2 вопрос - как вставить простую рекламу в приложение?

Самый простой вариант, конечно же, AdMob от Google, подробнее [тут](https://www.google.ru/admob/).

> Чтобы друзья кликали и как-нибудь за год соберу пару $

Настоятельно не рекомендую. Заработок с этого будет минимальный, а вот если в Google заметят, что клики стабильно идут от одних и тех же людей, то заблокируют аккаунт без возможности восстановления. Тем более, что минимальная сумма для вывода 100$, а с 5-6 человек это будет очень долго собираться.

Comment: Для AdMob нужно вносить деньги? Просто в android studio уже есть готовые шаблоны и хотел его попробовать. А спец акций типо "для бесплатных приложения", "для первого приложения", "для начинающих приложений" и тд - нету? (чтобы хотя бы 5, а не 25)

Comment: @ВладимирСалеев, никаких специальных акций нет. Деньги вносить в AdMob не нужно.