# Можно ли использовать карту Qiwi для регистрация аккаунта разработчика GooglePlay?

Tags: android, google-play

Я хочу зарегистрировать аккаунт разработчика и хочу воспользоваться картой Qiwi и у меня есть вопросы.

1. можно ли использовать карту киви?
2. какую карту лучше использовать qvc или qvv?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, может лучше закрыть как дубль вот этого [тык](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/387959/17609)? Там как раз про карту сказано.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  Отличная идея! Готово!

Answer (score 2):

[Выдержка](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6112435?hl=ru&ref_topic=3450769):

> Регистрационный сбор составляет 25 долларов США и взимается только один раз. Его можно оплатить банковской картой следующих типов:
>
> - MasterCard;
> - Visa;
> - American Express;
> - Discover (только в США);
> - Visa Electron (за пределами США).
>
> Примечание. В некоторых странах могут поддерживаться не все типы карт.

Comment: Моя вина, я регистрировался еще бесплатно. Изменяю ответ.

Comment: с меня взяли 25 + 1 доллар. Дополнительный доллар взял какой-то сервис-гугл. ;)

Comment: Должны вернуть этот доллар. Проверяют на способность платить.

Comment: проверил, действительно вернули. Благодарю.