# Регистрация в Google Play, оплата взноса, подтверждение личности

Tags: android, admob, google-play

Хочу зарегистрировать себе аккаунт в маркете.

В планах выливать туда свои приложения и монетизировать рекламой от AdMob (его тоже нужно зарегистрировать).

(Тема поднималась много раз, нашел множество достойных ответов, но все же хочу уточнить).

1. Стоит ли вводить свои настоящие данные (имя, фаилию и т.д.)?
2. Потребуют ли подтверждение личности? (возможно при выводе средств
   потом)
3. Какие еще надо аккаунты, чтобы добавить рекламу AdMob?
4. Можно ли иметь несколько аккаунтов в маркете? (допустим, я хочу на
   один выливать одни приложение, на другой другие)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Да стоит. Иначе могут возникнуть вопросы из-за различий в платёжной инфе и указанном в аккаунте.
2. По моему опыту потребовалось подтверждение только для AdMob. Присылали бумажное письмо домой.
3. Собственно для AdMob нужен аккаунт AdMob... Он отдельный от GooglePlay, можно (надо(?)) на ту же почту регать что и GooglePlay.
4. Врядли это поощряется и скорее всего запрещено. Как-то читал на хабре историю парня, чьи приложения постоянно банили, он создовал новые акки, но их тоже гугл вычислял и банил. Лучше не рисковать.

Похожие вопросы с ответами: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383937/17609) и [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/387959/17609)

Comment: Банили, так как уже нарушал. Если вы не нарушаете, то можете хоть сколько аккаунтов зарегистрировать.

Comment: @Suvitruf, откуда инфа? =) Я не читал соглашение с гуглом, может там и есть какие запреты)

Comment: https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ru/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html  Пункт 4.4 это не запрещает. Что не запрещено, то разрешено.

Comment: @Suvitruf, хм... А судя п.8 вообще это стандартная практика - иметь несколько акков на человека/организацию...

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Я правильно понял из комментариев, что можно одному человеку иметь несколько аккаунтов ?

Comment: @researcher, похоже что да, таки можно)