# Как несовершеннолетним подросткам зарабатывать в Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Мы с моим одноклассником(обоим по 17 лет) разработали приложение под Андроид.

Хотелось бы создать общий аккаунт разработчика в GP и получать деньги с рекламы во фришной версии и с покупок платной версии.

Как это можно сделать наиболее простым способом без совершеннолетних посредников?
Деньги необходимые для регистрации аккаунта имеются.

Comment: попросить родителей?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Comment: ну раз хочется без совершеннолетних посредников (ух как вы родителей назвали), тогда самый простой способ - подождать один год.

Comment: @kff, не согласен с Вами, на данном сайте куча вопросов с похожей тематикой. Вот, например, один из них http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383937/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-google-play-%D0%B8-admob

Comment: @delphikettle "Согласие есть продукт при полном непротивлении сторон!" За закрытие этого вопроса не только я. Сообщество рассудит.

Comment: Обсуждение данной тематики на мете: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2606

Comment: @kff ну вот, решили, что им тут место.

Comment: @kff для общества не будет лишним если Вы опубликуете свое мнение по данному вопросу в [теме обсуждения на мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2606/191745)

Comment: @Alex Моё мнение выражает зелёная галочка принятого ответа.

Comment: @kff там два ответа одинакового направления. Выше Вы хотите закрыть вопрос, и Вас, кстати говоря, 7 человек поддержало. Согласитесь, у Вас сомнения в нужности данного вопроса. Поэтому и пост на мете. И хотя голосование есть результат оценки,  для качественной оценки нужны ответы как ЗА так и ПРОТИВ. Тогда динамика будет более видна.

Comment: Ещё один похожий вопрос с ответом: [тык](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/387959/17609)

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Законы этого не позволяют. Только через посредников. Или ждите 18 лет. Тогда оформите всё на себя. Накопленные на гугловых счетах деньги никуда не денутся.