# Google Play, регистрация в Google Merchant, покупки внутри приложения, легальная сторона вопроса

Tags: android, google-play, admob, in-app-purchases

Закончил работу над своим первым приложеним с рекламой и возможностью покупки полной версии без рекламы и с дополнительными функциями, зарегистрировался в google play developer console, все оплатил.

Насколько я понял, что для того чтобы реализовать покупки внутри приложения нужен Google Merchant аккаунт. 
У меня есть несколько, возможно, глупых вопросов по этому поводу:

- У меня пока нет ни вебсайта ни доменного имени и нет пока возможности зарегистрировать (Могу ли я там использовать свою
  github.io страницу ?)
- Не совсем понимаю как нужно заполнять всю информацию для регистрации в Google Merchant, у меня нет ни ИП, ни компании. Можно ли обойтись без оформления оных ? Совсем не факт, что с приложения будут приходить значительные деньги, так что не знаю стоит ли все это лишних телодвижений прямо сейчас.
- Возможно ли сначала выложить работающее приложение, чтобы продажи шли, но не перечислялись на мой банковский счет, а потом уже при достаточной накопленной сумме зарегистрировать ИП, перевести средства на свой счет, заплатить налоги и т.д. ?
- Если я решу оставить лишь рекламу в приложении без покупки полной версии, нужен ли будет Google Merchant ? И как будет с выводом денег в этом случае ? Насколько я понимаю, деньги могут накапливаться на счете admob и их потом можно когда угодно вывести ?
  P.S. Нахожусь в России

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Сайт и домен не нужны - можете или не заполнять или да - гитХаб указать.
2. Ни ИП, ни компания не являются обязательным условием. Думаю, если вы ИП укажете, то не ошибётесь.
3. Да, вы можете копить сколь угодно деньги на гугловом счёту и лишь потом озаботиться созданием счёта своего для вывода. Деньги никуда не денутся.
4. Google Merchant нужен только для получения прибули из самого маркета. Рекламые доходу идут на другие счета и никак с самим маркетом не связаны.

Вот тут есть ещё полезной инфы о выводе денег с AdMob и Google Merchant:

1. [Вывод денег из аккаунтов Google Play и AdMob](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/383937/17609)
2. [Регистрация аккаунта разработчика Google Play и вывод денег в России](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/387959/17609)